# Why the notification doesn't show up after a long time

Tags: android

When I set the reminder time to several minutes, a notification is displayed. However, if the time is longer than one hour, the notification will not be displayed.

When I use `alarm.setRepeating` with 24 hours interval time it's works fine but I don't want user reminders to repeat. 
How to fix it?

AddReminder.java

```java
Intent nIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.context, ReminderReceiver.class);
            nIntent.putExtra("ID", newID);
            nIntent.putExtra("TITTLE", getString(R.string.reminder));
            nIntent.putExtra("TEXT", name);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.context, 0, nIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

ReminderReceiver.java

```java
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0);
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("TEXT");
        String tittle = intent.getStringExtra("TITTLE");

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainIntent, 0);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.finance43)
                .setContentTitle(tittle)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelId = "REMINDERS";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.reminders),
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            builder.setChannelId(channelId);
        }
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());

    }
```

Comment: [setExact](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%2520long,%2520android.app.PendingIntent)) might solve it

Comment: `setExact` is not working

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to take into account:

#### 1. You may have cancelled it inadvertently

The documentation of `AlarmManager.set` states the following:

> If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, that previous alarm will first be canceled

That means that if after setting an alarm you set another alarm with the same combination of intents and pending intents, then the previous alarm will be cancelled. Make sure your intents are unique unless your intention is to "replace" an existing alarm

#### 2. This alarm is inexact

Inexact alarms are configured using the `AlarmManager.set`, `AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating` methods and maybe a couple of more of them. Inexact alarms will not necessarily be triggered at the exact time you are expecting. This behaviour was introduced in API Level 19 as stated in the documentation:

> Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time, but may be deferred and delivered some time later

Use `setExact` if you want to trigger the alarm exactly at the time you requested

#### 3. Alarm cancelled by the system

All alarms are cancelled when the system shuts down. In other words, if you restart or power off your device, your alarms are also cancelled. An exception is repeating alarms, they will all fire as soon as the device boots up.

Make sure you keep track of your running alarms and then register a `BroadCastReceiver` to listen for the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast emitted by the system and restart your alarms

#### 4. The device is in idle/doze mode

Setting an alarm with `set` will cause the alarm not to trigger if the device is "dozing"/ idle. Use `setAndAllowWhileIdle` or `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`  if possible (introduced in API level 23, I think)

#### 5. Changing the device time zone/locale

This might cause unexpected results when using Real Time Clock (RTC) alarms because the application might translate well to other locales. Elapsed real time alarms scale much better than RTC alarms

Comment: Nice explanation for OP!